Duplicate two different planning scenes with Moveit
i use ROS-Noetic in ubuntu 20.04 with moveit framework.
I would like to duplicate a planning scene with moveit in order to have one planning scene which contains a static planning scene which i populate with an externally provided octomap. The other one instead i would like to it to contain only the update from sensors provided by the depth image octomap updater plugin.
this -> _opts = opts;
this -> _psm_ptr.reset( new planning_scene_monitor::PlanningSceneMonitor(ROBOT_DESCRIPTION, this -> _tf_buffer_ptr) );
this -> _psm_ptr -> startSceneMonitor(this -> _opts.planning_scene_monitor_topic);
this -> _psm_ptr -> startStateMonitor(this -> _opts.joint_states_topic, this -> _opts.attached_collision_topic);
this -> _psm_ptr -> startWorldGeometryMonitor(this -> _opts.collision_object_topic, this -> _opts.planning_scene_world_topic, this -> _opts.start_octomap_monitor);
this -> _psm_ptr -> startPublishingPlanningScene(planning_scene_monitor::PlanningSceneMonitor::SceneUpdateType::UPDATE_SCENE, "custom_monitor");
this -> _psm_ptr -> getStateMonitorNonConst() -> enableCopyDynamics(true);
this -> _psm_ptr -> providePlanningSceneService("/get_planning_scene_custom");

I used move_group for motion planning using a static preloaded octomap. I have initialized in my custom node a planning scene monitor as show above but with a different topic name respect ones of used by default move group. Therefore It seems that the octomap published are the same. As example:

when we use “clear octomap service” both are cleaned up.
i tried to add a cube trough the rviz motion planning plugin in the move_group
planning scene. I expected the cube to be visible
only in move_group planning scene however it is also visible in the
custom planning scene.
in rviz in the monitored custom scene, the octomap is not updated in PlanningScene
displayer. I just noticed that it is
possible to update it only if I close and reopen the PlanningScene
displayer.

Maybe the initialization (above) is not correct.
Could it be the both scene are in some way entangled? if not, do you have any idea why this happens and to clearly separate them?
Thank you for any helps
